# swift - CoreData EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x0))

Tags: swift, core-data

I am getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when I try to access my author item in my CoreData.

I am gettin the error when I try to access author.authorName

```
func setupAuthorList(){        
        var error: NSError?
        let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "AuthorList")
        let results = self.context!.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error) as! [AuthorList]

        if let _error = error {
            println("\(_error.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            for author in results {
                println("\(author.authorName)")
            }
        }
        self.authorLabel.text = author!.authorName
        let urlString = author!.authorImage
        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
        self.avatarImageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.avatarImageView.frame.size.width/2
        self.avatarImageView.clipsToBounds = true
        self.avatarImageView.hnk_setImageFromURL(url!)
        self.newspaperLabel.text = author!.newspaperName
    }
```

Comment: What `author` variable are you referring to in `self.authorLabel.text = author!.authorName` and the following lines? Where is it defined and where do you assign a value to it?

Comment: I made my string variable in coredata optional and it solved my issue...